# Synchronize two postgresql databases with current data using with bucardo

Tags: postgresql, replication, bucardo

I try to synchronize two databases using with bucardo. I create master to master replication and it works fine. However rows inserted before replication can not synchronize. I don't want dump one db to the other. How can I do that? Thanks for help.